# CLLocationManager-heading is not working with iPhone 6s and 6s Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am trying to receive heading (direction in which phone is pointed) for iPhone.

I am trying the code below,

```
- (void)startHeadingEvents {
   if (!self.locManager) {
      CLLocationManager* theManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

      // Retain the object in a property.
      self.locManager = theManager;
      locManager.delegate = self;
   }

   // Start location services to get the true heading.
   locManager.distanceFilter = 1000;
   locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
   [locManager startUpdatingLocation];

   // Start heading updates.
   if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
      locManager.headingFilter = 5;
      [locManager startUpdatingHeading];
   }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:    (CLHeading *)newHeading {
   if (newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0)
      return;

   // Use the true heading if it is valid.
   CLLocationDirection  theHeading = ((newHeading.trueHeading > 0) ?
        newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading);

   self.currentHeading = theHeading;
   [self updateHeadingDisplays];
}
```

Its similar to Apple's iOS developer library and programming guide.
The code always returns heading degree between 0 to 10 or 355 to 359. I don't get the values in between.

More, I get this problem only on iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S plus. Otherwise this is perfectly working on iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus. And my all phones are using the latest iOS.

Comment: Show me your updateHeadingDisplaysMethod

Comment: I help you show me your full coding

Comment: I tried your coding but I get confusion.It did not call the didUpdateHeading: method.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? It could be due to lack of calibration: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7246566